# Python fillna with Series sharing same index

Tags: python, pandas, loops, fillna

I have some null values on on column of my dataframe. I used a linear regression to predict the missing values but now I want to replace nan by the predicted value.
I would like to use the index as condition to fillna beacause I don't want all the other values beeing predicted.

here my null in the dataframe : df

```
    is      a       b       c       d       e       f
72  True    171.94  103.89  103.45  NaN     3.25    112.79
99  True    171.93  104.07  104.18  NaN     3.14    113.08
151 True    172.07  103.80  104.38  NaN     3.02    112.93
197 True    171.45  103.66  103.80  NaN     3.62    113.27
241 True    171.83  104.14  104.06  NaN     3.02    112.36
```

Here the Series return for the missing values to fill with index: prev

```
72      4.318525
99      4.393668
151     4.410457
197     4.319014
241     4.650617
```

I don't know what is the best to fill the missing values and I want to be sure is the correct values filled sharing same index position, with a loop for?

Comment: `df['d'].fillna(prev)`?

Comment: It would work but I would like to double check with index position to be sure

Comment: Use `prev = prev.sample(frac=1)` to shuffle your Series and check it :)

Comment: `fillna` aligns the index, there is nothing to double check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `fillna` (based on index)

```
df = df.fillna({'d': prev})

# OR

df['d'] = df['d'].fillna(prev)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
       is       a       b       c         d     e       f
72   True  171.94  103.89  103.45  4.318525  3.25  112.79
99   True  171.93  104.07  104.18  4.393668  3.14  113.08
151  True  172.07  103.80  104.38  4.410457  3.02  112.93
197  True  171.45  103.66  103.80  4.319014  3.62  113.27
241  True  171.83  104.14  104.06  4.650617  3.02  112.36
```

Comment: Thanks, it would work but I would like to double check with index position to be sure

Comment: Try `df = df.fillna({'d': prev.sample(frac=1)})`

Answer (score 2):

If the index's are the same (just make sure the data from your data df has the same column name as the dataframe you are mergine to i.e. 'd'):

```
df_merge = pd.merge(df, df_data, left_index = True, right_index = True, suffixes=('_x', '')).drop('d_x', axis = 1)
df_merge
```